Tkinter Notebook: Activate Button on Tab1 from Tab2
On Tab1 I have a Test button that can be "turned on" by pressing the Test button directly or by pressing the "activate button". From Tab2 I want to press "activate button on Tab 1" and have the Test button on Tab 1 "turn on" and show the green ON state. If I remove "Notebook" and have everything on one page it will work but it's when I have two tabs I cannot show the Test button in the ON state by activating it from Tab 2.
 #!/usr/bin/python3.9
    
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
    
class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

    
        self.labelA = ttk.Label(self, text = "This is MainFrame")
        self.labelA.grid(column=1, row=1, padx = 30, pady = 30)
    
        self.buttonA = tk.Button(self, text="test", command=self.button)
        self.buttonA.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=20)
        self.buttonA.config(relief="raised", bg="gray", font='Helvetica 14', width='4', height='1', bd='8')

        self.buttonB = tk.Button(self, text="activate TEST button", command=self.button) #button)
        self.buttonB.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=20)

        self.buttonC = tk.Button(self, text="get time from Tab 2", command=self.get_time)
        self.buttonC.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=40, pady=20)


    def button(self):

        if self.buttonA.config('relief')[-1] == 'raised':
            self.buttonA.config(relief='sunken', text="ON", bg='green', font='Helvetica 14',  width='4', height='1', bd='8')    

        else:
            if self.buttonA.config('relief')[-1] != 'raised':
                self.buttonA.config(relief="raised", text="test", bg="gray", font='Helvetica 14', width='4', height='1')

    def get_time(self):
        self.Frame2.get_time()

            
class SubFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
    
    
        self.labelB = ttk.Label(self, text = "This is SubFrame")
        self.labelB.grid(column=1, row=2, padx = 30, pady = 30)
    
        self.buttonB = tk.Button(self, text="activate button in MainFrame", command=self.test)
        self.buttonB.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=40, pady=20)

        self.buttonD = tk.Button(self, text="get time", command=self.get_time)
        self.buttonD.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=40, pady=20)
       
        ## ENTRY STYLE
        style = {'fg': 'black', 'bg': 'white', 'font': 'Helvetica 14 bold', 'width':'6', 'bd':'2', 
                        'highlightbackground':"black", 'justify':'center', 'relief':'sunken',
                        'insertontime': '0', 'takefocus': '0' } # highlightcolor':"red"
    
        self.entry1_var=tk.StringVar()
        #self.entry1_var.set("00:00")
        self.entry1=tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry1_var, width=5, justify="center",)
        self.entry1.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=(0, 0), pady=(0,10))
        self.entry1.configure(style)

    def get_time(self):
        print (self.entry1.get())
    
    def test(self):
        self.Frame1.button()

    
class App(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
        self.geometry('800x500')
        #self.resizable(False, False)
        self.title("TABS")

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.Frame1 = MainFrame(self.notebook)
        self.Frame2 = SubFrame(self.notebook)

        self.Frame1.Frame2 = self.Frame2
        self.Frame2.Frame1 = self.Frame1

        self.notebook.add(self.Frame1, text='TAB 1')
        self.notebook.add(self.Frame2, text='TAB 2')

        self.notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W) #pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
        
    app = App()

    app.mainloop()


Note that mFrame and sFrame are invisible frames because no layout manager is used on them.

Basically it ia similar issue as your other question.

@acw1668 can you show me with code? I don't understand what you mean.

@acw1668 you were correct. I have modified the code above to function as I wanted but can someone explain why self.Frame1.Frame2 = self.Frame2 and
self.Frame2.Frame1 = self.Frame1 is needed?

The answer to your other question has already explained why.  So what you need to understand is not why they are needed, but why they work.

Your code functions with Python version 3.12.7 onwards.
It is recommended to upgrade to Python 3.12.7.

From Tab2 I want to press "activate button on Tab 1" and have the
Test button on Tab 1 "turn on" and show the green ON state.


Insert self.buttonB.config within the button(self) method.

Snippet:
def button(self):

    if self.buttonA.config('relief')[-1] == 'raised':
        self.buttonA.config(relief='sunken', text="ON", bg='green', font='Helvetica 14',  width='4', height='1', bd='8')    
        self.buttonB.config(text="ON") # <== Add this.
    else:
        if self.buttonA.config('relief')[-1] != 'raised':
            self.buttonA.config(relief="raised", text="test", bg="gray", font='Helvetica 14', width='4', height='1')

            self.buttonB.config(text="activate TEST button") # <== Add this.

Screenshot(only shows buttonB activation):

